# How do you know which plugin is consuming CPU?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, cpu

My Wordpress site is going down from time to time, I see in the server log that wp-load is requested a lot, I blocked external requests to this file. But I still get 5xx error once a day, I have a lot of plugins, and my server settings are good. But how do I determine which plugin is causing this issue?

Comment: I imagine you would disable plugins and re-enable them using a process of elimination. Why do you have lots of plugins? IMHO, using many plugins on WP is death by a thousand paper cuts, and a security nightmare.

Comment: How do you know it is a plugin that is the problem opposed to a flood of requests for pages that are more CPU intensive?

Comment: A thought - you said you are getting 5xx errors once a day.  These errors should be logged in the web server log and should give you a hint of something that can be fixed.